# Как удалить дубликаты строк в массиве?

Tags: python, массивы, pandas, numpy

Дан массив NumPy:

```
[[1 0 1 0 0 1]
 [1 1 1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1 1]
 [1 0 1 0 0 1]]

a = [[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
     [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
     [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
     [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
     [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]]

 b = np.array(a)
```

Как можно удалить дубликаты строк? То есть, на выходе должно получится:

```
[[1 0 1 0 0 1]
 [1 1 1 0 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1 1]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

воспользуйтесь [np.unique(arr, axis=0)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
In [23]: np.unique(b, axis=0)
Out[23]:
array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

---

если нужно сохранить порядок строк:

```
u, idx = np.unique(b, axis=0, return_index=True)
res = u[idx.argsort()]
```

результат:

```
In [33]: res
Out[33]:
array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]])
```